# Verify element appears or not on the page avoid NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, page-factory

Error msg appears on the site if any error occurs dynamically. In my case, if error occurs, popup appears and I need to click on OK button.

The problem is, using all Selenium tricks, I cannot avoid NoSuchElementException, or 'Cannot click on element' exceptions. Expectation: If error popup appears, click on OK, if not, just go on and skip these ifs.I'm following this approach:

PageFactory Element and methods.

```
@FindBy(id='locator')
List<WebElement> errorElement1;

@FindBy(id='locator2')
List<WebElement> errorElement2;

Usage:

if(errorElement1.size() > 0) {
errorElement1.get(0).click();
}

if(errorElement2.size() > 0) {
errorElement2.get(0).click();
}
```

The problem, if I use errorElement1.isDisplayed method, I got NosuchElementException.

I tried all tricks what can be found here, no success so far. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you guys, I will mark the answer soon, I'm trying to implement all the options and will get back to you when its working fine! Thanks All, appreciate it!

Comment: Can you clarify if these error popups related to the currently executing test case or of some process running in the background which are no relation to the executing test case? If these are of the former, then it should be handled case by case and if an error SHOULD occur and popup does not appear then test should fail and vice versa. But if later, as of background process error message then you need to reach out to the developers to have a framework to turn these off for testing. Maybe by setting a cookie or a flag. Just handling click will not manage all cases when popup shows up.

Comment: @Grasshopper: Thank you! Not related to my test case, no relation at all.Given the site, with several external systems, 'A' gives us a search result, 'B' handles calculations. Doesn't matter. Something went wrong on the environment, warning messages appears on the UI. (not error page, just on the design) No popup. The thing is, when one external system is down, or something happens, the site is not going to be down, working fine with all UI component, just a warning messages appears. I'd like to check these warning msgs. If it appears, throw an exception. If not, just continue the test.

Comment: @Grasshopper: My idea is that, One helper class contains all error elements (PageFactory) and only one robust method check everything. When I call this method, the framework iterates over all error elements on the site and if one is visible, throw an exception. If not, continue. In this case I could use it everywhere because only one big fat error validator handles all error msgs. isDisplayed and List<WebElements> size in IF doesn't work. Try catch would be useful, but I have no idea how could be implemented this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for the presence of an element, the way I usually do it is to do something like this:

```
try {
    errorElement1.get(0).click();
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    // the element isn't present on the page, you can do something about it here
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about the try catch but if the elements is not presented on the page, I just wanna move on, nothing to do there in this case...

Comment: In that case, you could leave the catch block empty, or add a log statement that at gives a logger trail indicating that it happened that way if you care to

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining all your page elements as lists, only define the ones that are actually potentially lists as lists, define the rest as web elements.  What I do is write a function in a helper file to check for the existence of any element defined by specifically checking for null value first.  The function is probably overkill for what you're looking for, but I use it as a wrapper and simply define a function for elements that I need to check inside the page object class, like okButtonIsDisplayed() and inside call the below wrapper, passing the webelement defined, a descriptive string for logging of errors, and a boolean determining whether or not the element -should- exist for pass/fail reasons.

```
public static Boolean pomIsDisplayed(WebElement ele, String eleName, String passOrFail) {
    /*
     * This function returns true if the passed WebElement is displayed
     * 
     * @Param ele - The WebElement being tested
     * 
     * @Param eleName - The textual description of the WebElement for
     * logging purposes.
     * 
     * @Param passOrFail - "Pass" if log should show pass unless unexpected
     * exception occurs. "Fail" is the default if not specified and will log
     * a failure if not displayed.
     * 
     * Returns true - The WebElement is displayed false - The WebElement is
     * not displayed
     */
    String stsStart = " " + passOrFail + ": Element " + eleName;
    Boolean isDisplayed = false;
    String stsMsg = stsStart + " is NOT displayed";
    try {
        if (ele.equals(null))
            stsMsg = stsStart + " is NOT found";
        else if ("checkbox".equals(ele.getAttribute("type")) || "radio".equals(ele.getAttribute("type"))) {
            isDisplayed = true;
            stsMsg = " Pass: Element " + eleName + " is displayed";
        } else if (!ele.isDisplayed())
            stsMsg = stsStart + " is NOT displayed";
        else {
            isDisplayed = true;
            stsMsg = " Pass: Element " + eleName + " is displayed";
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException | NullPointerException e) {
        stsMsg = stsStart + " is NOT found. Cause: " + e.getCause();
    } catch (ElementNotVisibleException e1) {
        stsMsg = stsStart + " is NOT displayed. Cause: " + e1.getCause();
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        stsMsg = " Fail: Element " + eleName + " Exception error. Cause: " + e2.getCause();
    }
    addresult(stsMsg);
    return isDisplayed;
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I only define those elements, which can be appeared on the page. Different errors, different popups. How does your code work if the element is not displayed? Just move on and if the element exists on the page, proceed? I do not need any logging, just performing action, like click.

Comment: The pomIsDisplayed function returns a boolean true if the element exists and is displayed.  What happens as a result of that is up to the test itself.  If using TestNG or JUnit, the coder could perform an Assert.Fail() in the test case as a result, depending on whether or not the element should exist, and whether or not the test can continue if it does not, for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to handle this. You could write a `click()` method that handles clicking the element collection that you are currently using.

```
public void click(List<WebElement> e)
{
    if (!e.isEmpty())
    {
        e.get(0).click();
    }
}
```

You would use it like

```
click(errorElement1);
```

You could change the `List` to just a `WebElement`

```
@FindBy(id='locator')
WebElement errorElement1;
```

and use something like

```
public void click(WebElement e)
{
    try
    {
        e.click();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // catch and handle various exceptions
    }
}
```

You would call it like

```
click(errorElement1);
```

Another way to handle this scenario would be to write a function that checks for each error element and clicks on it using the `click()` method above.

```
public void handleErrors()
{
    click(errorElement1);
    click(errorElement2);
}
```

So your script would look like

```
// do some action
handleErrors();
// do another action
```

---

How to check if the errors exist using your current locators

```
public boolean errorsExist()
{
    return !errorElement1.isEmpty() || !errorElement2.isEmpty();
}
```

You can just check to see if either collection contains any elements. If either does, an error exists. If you need to know which error exists, you would want to break this function up into two functions, one for each error element.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for that. So lets assume: I use try catch to check warning visibility. If warning is displayed on the page, lets throw an error. If not, just go on and proceed. How can I handle these "various cases"? Sorry for this dump question, but I'm not sure how should I handle this. (using if, if(warning.isDisplayed) {throw error} without else. But I'm not sure with try catch.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Still not totally sure what you are looking for. So I mention my assumptions -

1. The connected system fails but the site is running fine with no interference on the UI. That means no popups or modal alerts.
2. Some specific area on the page where these messages appear which do not hinder any page functionality.
3. When a message is visible you want to verify the message and throw an exception to end the test. This part is confusing because in the original post you mention clicking a OK button. But in comments you mention throwing and exception.
4. There maybe multiple systems so used a map instead of pageobjects to store them.

You will need to pass the webdriver to the `ErrorChecker` class, a constructor would be easiest with pico container. You may look at the inner class if you want to change it. To include a new system message just create a static key and update the map with the details.

To call this `ErrorChecker` code you will need to put it inside a try catch to get hold of the checked `SystemFailureException`.

> public class ErrorChecker {
>
> ```
>   //As you are using picocontainer create a constructor with the driver as argument.
>   private WebDriver driver;
>
>   private static final Map<String, ErrorMsg> errMap = new HashMap<>();
>
>   private static final String SYSTEM_A_ID = "sysakey";
>   private static final String SYSTEM_B_ID = "sysbkey";
>   private static final String SYSTEM_C_ID = "sysckey";
>
>   static {
>       //First parameter - By for locating the message
>       //Second paremeter - By for locating the OK button
>       //Third parameter - Expected Message
>       errMap.put(SYSTEM_A_ID, new ErrorMsg(By.id("ida"),By.xpath("xpa"), "ExpectedMsgA"));
>       errMap.put(SYSTEM_B_ID, new ErrorMsg(By.id("idb"),By.xpath("xpb"), "ExpectedMsgB"));
>       errMap.put(SYSTEM_C_ID, new ErrorMsg(By.id("idc"),By.xpath("xpc"), "ExpectedMsgC"));
>   }
>
>   public void verifyErrors() throws SystemFailureException{
>       Set<String> keys = errMap.keySet();
>
>       for(String key : keys) {
>           ErrorMsg err = errMap.get(key);
>           System.out.println(err);
>
>           try {
>               //If this fails with NoSuchElement(ie appropriate msg is missing) 
>               //then control goes to catch.
>               //Loops to next key or system.
>               WebElement msgBox = driver.findElement(err.msgBy);
>
>               //Reaches here then msg for failng system found
>               String msg = msgBox.getText();
>
>               //Verify if correct. If this is required to be done.
>               Assert.assertEquals("Error message mismatch.", err.expectedMessage, msg);
>
>               //Click to make it disappear. Though does not make sense as exception
>               //be thrown to break process.
>               driver.findElement(err.okbtnBy).click();
>
>               //Throw the exception that systems are failing and break out of loop.
>               throw new SystemFailureException(key + " gone kaput.");             
>
>           } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
>               System.out.println("catch do nothing");
>           }
>       }
>   }
>
>   private static class ErrorMsg{
>       public By msgBy; 
>       public By okbtnBy;
>       public String expectedMessage;
>
>       public ErrorMsg(By msgBy, By okbtnBy, String expectedMessage) {
>           this.msgBy = msgBy;
>           this.okbtnBy = okbtnBy;
>           this.expectedMessage = expectedMessage;
>       }
>
>       @Override
>       public String toString() {
>           return "ErrorMsg [msgBy=" + msgBy
>                   + ", okbtnBy=" + okbtnBy
>                   + ", expectedMessage=" + expectedMessage + "]";
>       }
>
>   }
> }
> ```

The custom exception class.

> ```
> public class SystemFailureException extends Exception {
>
>   public SystemFailureException() {
>   }
>
>   public SystemFailureException(String message) {
>       super(message);
>   }
>
>   public SystemFailureException(Throwable cause) {
>       super(cause);
>   }
>
>   public SystemFailureException(String message, Throwable cause) {
>       super(message, cause);
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi! Second and third point is correct. Some specific area on the page where these messages appears and the message becomes visible and I want to verify/catch this message and trow an exception. if no error in the backend, this message is not visible for the users. This is the easiest way for me to check the UI warnings. Your solution still valid in this case? Sorry if I was confusing.

Comment: More important is the first point. These messages should not interfere with the webpage. If it does then this will work intermittently. As you mentioned there are no popups, so the solution should work. Give it a shot with fingers crossed...

Comment: Though you will need to modify the classes to remove the ok button locator and click call..

Comment: It was my bad Grasshopper. I just merged my two problems(previous questions, robust error handler). You are right, this problem is handle the popups and click ok. Shame on me. The common thing is that, something just appears and need to handle it.

Comment: With modal popups appearing dynamically from a separate process, you need to contact developers to suppress them for testing. For the error handler this should work.